# Silk UI not loading: ERROR CODE 103 - Enable JavaScript to run this app

Tags: django, django-silk

I'm experiencing an issue while trying to access the Silk statistics for my Django app. When I request the corresponding URL (http://localhost:8000/silk/),
I'm getting the following response  even though JS is enabled in the browser:

```
 ERROR CODE 103: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

Interestingly, instead of showing the Silk UI, it displays the UI of my React app, which makes API calls to the Django app.

In my Django Settings.py file, I have the Silk middleware configured as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
]
```

Furthermore, I can confirm that Silk operations are being logged in the console, indicating that data is being successfully recorded in the database.

I think that this tool would be very useful for me to be able to do an analysis of the performance of my Django app, but until now I have not been able to make it work completely. Any help, thanks in advance!